# Namespace extensions - SetCurrentViewMode FVM_TILE is medium sized and not large?

Tags: c++, shell-extensions

i'm trying to set large icons by default for namespace extensions,
eventually i'm doing on an IFolderView -> SetCurrentViewMode into FVM_TILE,
the view is indeed Tile (if you can do right click - check the view) - but it's medium icons, and not Large as mentioned here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775618(v=vs.85).aspx

i've tried all enum combinations, there's no way choosing large icons.

is there a solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my NSE I do the following: my NSE implements IFolderViewSettings. When shell calls IFolderViewSettings.GetViewMode I return FLVM_ICONS and when shell calls IFolderViewSettings.GetIconSize I return 256. As result shell use ExtraLarge icon mode by default.

But if you want to use Set* functions it it better to use IFolderView2.SetViewModeAndIconSize.

Comment: Nice! 
SetViewModeAndIconSize with "Auto" and 128 did the trick.

many thanks!